# Add NAs into pipe creating a data frame

Tags: r, sorting, filter, slice, rows

I have a fairly straightforward dataframe with 49 id's, and many x and y values for each id. It looks something like this:

```
id    x    y
1     1    2
1     2    3
1     3    5
1     4    6
1     5    6
1     6    7
2     1    0
2     2    0
2     3    1
2     4    1
2     5    1
2     6    2
2     7    2
3     1    2
3     2    3
3     3    4
4     1    2
4     2    2 
4     3    3
4     4    4
4     5    4
4     6    5
etc.
```

I want to create a smaller dataframe with one value of x and one matching value for y for each id. This value for x must meet a condition, for instance being greater than or equal to 4. If this condition is not met, in my current code the id is simply discarded. Instead, I want a N/A to be filled in as the x and y values for that id. I currently have the following code:

```
df2 <- df %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        filter(VAS >= 4) %>%
        slice(1) %>%
        ungroup()
```

This gives the following result:

```
id    x    y
1     5    6
2     6    2
4     4    4
6     7    3
7     4    5
etc.
```

What I would like instead is the following:

```
id    x    y
1     5    6
2     6    2
3     N/A  N/A
4     4    4
5     N/A  N/A
6     7    3
7     4    5
etc.
```

How could I add this condition?

Comment: Include your original data, You have just included the results

Comment: `group_by(id, .drop = FALSE)` ?

Comment: `tidyr::complete` and `tidyr::fill`

Comment: please add the output of `dput(df2)`